# Sharing a directory between Termux and another application (PasswdSafe)

Tags: applications, storage, termux

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0". I haven't rooted the device (and don't really want to).

Until today, I was running Android 10. Today I installed an update that upgraded it to Android 11.

I'm using Termux (now installed from F-Droid) and [PasswdSafe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jefftharris.passwdsafe). (CORRECTION: I *thought* I was using the F-Droid version.)

Until now, I've been using Termux commands to copy my password database into a directory under `/storage/emulated/0/data` and using PasswdSafe to access it. After the update from Android 10 to 11, I can no longer access that directory from Termux. (The Unix permissions imply I should be able to; obviously there's an Android-specific restriction.)

```
$ ls -ld /storage/emulated/0/data
drwxrwx--- 4 root everybody 4096 Jun  9 21:12 /storage/emulated/0/data
$ groups
u0_a192 inet everybody u0_a192_cache all_a192
$ cd /storage/emulated/0/data
bash: cd: /storage/emulated/0/data: Permission denied
$
```

Ideally, I would like to have a directory such that both Termux and PasswdSafe have read/write access. Read/write access for Termux and read-only access for PasswdSafe would also work.

I also have an SD card mounted as `/storage/0000-0000`.

**UPDATE**: I thought I was using the version from F-Droid rather than from the Play Store, but both the Play Store and F-Droid on the device say I have termux version 0.101, while https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/ says the current version is 0.117. There may be a conflict, perhaps introduce when I did a factory reset a few weeks ago (it may have automatically reinstalled the Play Store version). I'll try completely uninstalling termux from the Play store and then installing from F-Droid.

**UPDATE 2**: I had *thought* that updating to the latest version Termux from F-Droid had fixed the problem, but there's still something odd (and possibly sporadic) going on. I'm not currently able to update files under `/storage/emulated/0/data`, or to `cd` to that directory. But I have files under that directory that were updated after I upgraded to Android 11, so I was able to at some point. I'll try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: For what purpose do you need access to the folder used by PasswdSafe? If you use it for synchronizing a password database file this should better be done by a plugin that runs inside the password manager. For example I use Keepass2Android + Dropbox + a keyfile that is never synced anywhere (so password brute forcing the password database will not work without the keyfile). So no matter who get access to the file in dropbox the file is useless to that attacker.

Comment: @Robert I prefer to manage the password database myself without storing anything in the cloud. More generally, I like to use Termux to manage files on my device, including files used by other applications. In Android 10, I could do that. In Android 11, I can't. I'll consider other solutions if necessary, but I'd prefer to doing what I do now.

Comment: Then may be you should consider to change where the db file is stored and how it is accessed by PasswdSafe. Have you tried to store the file in the app-private directory of termux and "send" it to PasswdSafe via Intent containing a link to a Termux content provider serving the db file? Alternatively there would be `/data/local/tmp` left where both apps can write if they know the file-name (directory has AFAIR no x flag set).

Comment: Yes, changing where the db file is stored is the point of my question. I want to create or update the file in termux and then access it (ideally read/write, but read-only would be acceptable) in PasswdSafe. What is `/data/local/tmp`? I don't see anything by that name. Possibly `tmux-share` might be part of the solution; I'll have to investigate how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get termux from f-droid . The play store version isnt capable of doing advanced stuff on modern versions of android

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm already using Termux from F-Droid. But both the Play Store and F-Droid say that I have version 0.101 installed, and https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/ says the current version is 0.117. It may be that the Play Store version was reinstalled after I did a factory reset a few weeks ago. I'll try completely uninstalling the Play Store version and installing again from F-Droid.

Comment: That was the problem. Deleting the Play Store version of Termux (version 0.101) and installing the current version from F-Droid fixed the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson my pleasure i could help you

Comment: I'm particularly impressed (?) that I explicitly said in the question that I was using the F-Droid version, and you correctly said that the problem was that I *wasn't* using the F-Droid version.

Comment: I'm now unable to update files in `/storage/emulated/0/data` from Termux. I don't know what's going on; the behavior I'm seeing is inconsistent.

Comment: @KeithThompson though you explicitly mentioned you were using the fdroid version, i judged that you simply updated it over the play store version without uninstalling the play store one , and i was right